# Cannot activate bluetooth on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, 22.04, bluetooth

I have installed Bluez following online directions to use with a Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode). I know the dongle works because it is perfect on my Windows device.

When I run `lsusb` I can see my Bluetooth dongle.

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

When I run `systemctl start bluetooth`

```
Failed to start bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists
See system logs and 'systemctl status bluetooth.service' for details.
```

When I run `systemctl status bluetooth.service`

```
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: error (Reason: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
bluetooth.service: Two services allocated for the same bus name org.bluez, refusing operation.
```

I've tried removing BlueZ with no success using `sudo apt remove bluez pulseaudio-module-bluetooth blueman`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'blueman' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'pulseaudio-module-bluetooth' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bluez
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 3,759 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 1257563 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing bluez (5.64-0ubuntu1) ...
Failed to stop bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--remove):
 installed bluez package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Failed to start bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists
See system logs and 'systemctl status bluetooth.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "start" failed.
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: error (Reason: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

bluetooth.service: Two services allocated for the same bus name org.bluez, refusing operation.
```

And with `sudo dpkg -r --force-all bluez`

```
(Reading database ... 1257563 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing bluez (5.64-0ubuntu1) ...
Failed to stop bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--remove):
 installed bluez package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Failed to start bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists
See system logs and 'systemctl status bluetooth.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "start" failed.
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: error (Reason: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

bluetooth.service: Two services allocated for the same bus name org.bluez, refusing operation.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed bluez package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluez
```

Finally, `systemctl restart bluetooth.service` also did not work

```
Failed to restart bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists
See system logs and 'systemctl status bluetooth.service' for details.
```

I am overall just very stuck.

Comment: Check if a snap package with "bluetooth" is installed. But strange behaviour not to uninstall a package. As far as I know you can have either `blueman` or `bluez`, not both

Comment: @kanehekili `snap list` gets no results for either of the bluetooth packages. I only get information for: `core20`, `core22`, `lxd`, and `snapd`

Answer (score 3):

1. Restart Bluetooth Service:

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

2. Install Bluetooth Manager (Optional):

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

3. Update Your System:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

4. Check Bluetooth Status:

```
rfkill list
```

5. Reset Bluetooth Settings:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/bluetooth/
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

6. Verify Bluetooth Modules:

```
lsmod | grep bluetooth
```

7. Check Logs for Errors:

```
journalctl | grep -i bluetooth
```

**Note:** If none of these steps resolve the issue, it's possible that there may be a hardware compatibility problem, or there might be a more specific issue with your system.

Answer (score 0):

The `bluez` snap uses the same DBus name. Having that installed at the same time with the `bluez` Debian package would cause such a conflict.

Check if the snap is installed:

```
snap list bluez
```

If yes, remove it:

```
sudo snap remove bluez
```

and then start the failed bluetooth service:

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Comment: Unfortunately my snap list isn't showing that `bluez` was installed using snap